# Generic method compile time error

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

The following code:

```
    private IList<T> DoStuff<T>()
    {
        IList<T> res = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            T item = DoOtherStuff<T>();
            res.Add(item);
        }
        return res;
    }

    private T DoOtherStuff<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
```

Generates the following error:

> > 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DoOtherStuff()'

Please may somebody explain why?

Comment: `DoOtherStuff` requires a default constructor but `DoStuff` does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
private IList<T> DoStuff<T>()
```

to

```
private IList<T> DoStuff<T>() where T : new()
```

since otherwise you can't guarantee that `T` has a `new()` constructor.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `DoOtherStuff<T>` method has the `where T : new()` constraint. (That is, "`T` must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor".)

Your `DoStuff<T>` method doesn't have that constraint, which means that the compiler can't guarantee that all type arguments `T` that can legally be used for `DoStuff` will meet the `where T : new()` constraint required by `DoOtherStuff`.

Answer (score 2):

`DoOtherStuff`'s `T` specifies that `T : new()`, which means it has a public parameterless constructor.  `DoStuff`'s `T` has no restrictions, so you might not be able to say `new T()`.  You should add `where T : new()` do `DoStuff`.